# Preserve colours when piping to tee

Tags: colors, tee, homebrew

I have made a little program where I update Homebrew with `brew update`, then send the output to a log file, but I also want to keep it on the terminal, so I use `tee`. The problem is, it doesn't show colours, for example, when I get this error message:

```
Error: Failed to update tap: caskroom/cask
```

The word `Error` is supposed to be in red, but it isn't when outputting it with `tee`. I haven't found a way to solve this, so does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Can you tell `homebrew` to always use colors? It is likely detecting that `stdout` isn't a shell and is disabling colors.

Comment: @saiarcot895 How would I do that? The man-page doesn't mention anything of the sort.

Comment: You could try `--colors`, but if the manpage doesn't mention it, then it probably won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Like most utilities that produce colourized text output by default, the `brew` utility removes the colour codes from its output if the output is not going directly to a terminal.

By setting the `HOMEBREW_COLOR` environment variable for the utility, you may force `brew` to produce colourized output even if you're piping it to some command:

```bash
HOMEBREW_COLOR=1 brew update | tee brew-update-colour.log
```

This is documented in the "ENVIRONMENT" section of the `brew(1)` manual:

> `HOMEBREW_COLOR`
> If set, force colour output on non-TTY outputs.